# Is there a way to make Ubuntu read out notifications?

Tags: notify-osd, text-to-speech

Ubuntu has a very cool notification system. Is there a way to make Ubuntu read out notifications when they appear?

Or is it possible to link the text in notifications to `espeak`?

Comment: This https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/345357 states orca did not and now does again(?)

Comment: orca reads everything and is very annoying what am looking for is a way to read only the notifications 
anyway thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**This question is really interesting so as the answer.**

`dbus-monitor` when executed waits for the signal and when arrives it catches and gives the appropriate information about it. Similarly it can be executed to get the info about **Notifications**. When executed:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered "member=Notify\|string"
```

It will wait for the notifications and when any notification arrives it gives the information of the notifications.

For example when sound is increased/decreased or any song track is changed or any other it gives the message. I'm manually creating a desktop notification using `notify-send`  command on any other terminal:

```
notify-send "Hello How are you?"
```

Then the first terminal in which `dbus-monitor` command is executing will give message like:

```
saurav@saurav-P4I45Gx-PE:~$ dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered "member=Notify\|string"
   string ":1.473"
method call sender=:1.474 -> dest=:1.475 serial=7    path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications;  member=Notify
   string "notify-send"
   string ""
   string "Hello How Are You?"
   string ""
         string "urgency"
```

Now above output can be easily passed to `espeak` to read message. 
For example,

**Replacing the above `dbus-monitor` command with following will read the notification message:**

**Check, How does it work:**

- Execute this command in a terminal and leave it running:

  ```
  dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered "string" | grep --line-buffered -e method -e ":" -e '""' -e urgency -e notify -v | grep --line-buffered '.*(?=string)|(?<=string).*' -oPi | grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' | xargs -I '{}' espeak {}
  ```

  <sub>I know it has become very long, but there is no other way to make it small because the filtering of actual notification made it lengthy.</sub>
- Then run a desktop notification either the way I described above using `notify-send` or any thing else. I'm using `notify-send`. So executing following command in other terminal:

  ```
  notify-send "Hello! I am Saurav Kumar."
  ```

  As soon as you execute the command it will speak(read) the notification.

Although it ate my 4-5 hours, but I'm happy now to make it working.

**You can also make your own command like `saynoti`** and execute it every time you want a reading notification. By following these steps you can do so:

- First save the actual command to a file called `saynoti`. You can use any file name that will become your actual command name.
- Then make the file executable and move or copy it to `/bin`:

  ```
  chmod +x saynoti
  sudo cp saynoti /bin
  ```
- Now you can simply execute your new command to start **Speaking Notification**:

  ```
  saynoti
  ```
- To kill the running process you can execute this command:

  ```
  pkill dbus-monitor
  ```

  or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on the terminal where `saynoti` is running.
- You can also run `saynoti` every time your system starts by making it a [start-up application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

I would like to say thank you for this question. Because of this question, I learned a lot of things. :)

Reply if you get any problem or need any further change/modification. I'm sure you will  be happy to get the final working version.

Comment: @Meow: Sounds good that you're pleased with the outcome. In future if you'll need any modification, just ping me here.

Comment: @Meow: Check the final working version. I solved all the issue and it is working great. You will be happy to get this version.

Comment: dude u'r awesome can't ask anything else; i placed it in my startup list and it works flawlessly merci beaucoup

Comment: from where did you learn about `dbus-monitor`, I want to start learning

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: You can learn it from its official site about Dbus and Dbus-Monitor.
1. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/
2. http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I had troubble with extra " in my email addresses hence I have added this
to the code line above as espeak needs no " at all to read out ;)

| sed 's/\"//g' |

=>

| grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' | sed 's/\"//g' | xargs -I '{}' espeak {}

COOL work. Better by far than tweaking notify-send lib itself 4 "Hello! I am Saurav Kumar."

update: does not work steady. I will use | tee -a $file |