# How to disable system tray notifications in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, notify-osd

I don't like, need nor want the notification bubbles which pop up in the top right corner of the screen. I've looked around quite a bit but can't identify how to disable them?

NotifyOSD Configuration let's me change the look of them, but not get rid of them. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the output of `grep -r -i org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/` & `ps ax | grep -i notif`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)

Comment: Hi @Empty , did you notice you have a new answer? Since you edited your question, I assumed you were looking for one, wrong assumption?

Comment: ubuntu is such a lame sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

To completely turn off notifications, open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type the following command:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
```

Finally restart your system to open a new session without notifications bubbles.

Comment: Didn't work (blah blah blah)

Comment: `sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd` doesn't work either :-(

Comment: @Empty what is with the blah blah blah

Comment: What I wanted to say was "Didn't work" but apparently that was too short so it was necessary to add something pointless to the end of it. blah blah blah seemed appropriately pointless. If you've got a better suggestion perhaps you can edit my comments and change "blah blah blah" to something else? All the best Trevor!

Answer (score 3):

#### Effectively disable notifications without messing with your system

A shamelessly ugly, but guaranteed perfectly working solution below. Although it *is* ugly, I can't see a real downside, and when no other options seem to exist or work, I believe we are excused.

#### The solution

From [this nice answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368611/is-there-a-way-to-make-ubuntu-read-out-notifications/368875#368875), we learn that you can keep an eye on upcoming notifications. If we edit the command in that answer a bit, to simply kill the notification *before* it actually pops up, we effectively disable notifications. The set up:

1. Create a small script with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered "string" | grep --line-buffered -e method -e ":" -e '""' -e urgency -e notify -v | grep --line-buffered '.*(?=string)|(?<=string).*' -oPi | grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' | xargs -I '{}' pkill notify-osd
   ```
2. Save it as `nonotifications.sh`, and ***make it executable***
3. Test- run it by running in a terminal:

   ```
   /path/to/nonotifications.sh
   ```

   (keep it running)
4. If all works fine, add it to your Startup Applications. Choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /path/to/nonotifications.sh"
   ```

#### Additional options

The fun part is that the solution can be connected to a script, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/697973/72216), to (for example) only *allow* certain notifications, or only *disable* specific ones.

Comment: This actually works, and it is even a possibility to mute notifications temporarily (like during a meeting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dconf Editor to disable the notifications.  To install dconf editor, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Once installed, type dconf in Dash, and then click on dconf Editor.  Once open navigate to com --> canonical --> indicator --> and disable the ones you want.

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything under there for message bubbles?

Comment: What message bubble are you referring to?  Can you add and screen-shot?