# How do I disable application notification popups?

Tags: notification

I hate these popups at the top of the screen.

[image]

I can't see how to turn them off. As you can see, the notification settings seems to indicate they are turned off.

How do I get rid of them? I believe it's NotifyOSD, but I'm not sure. I don't want to remove other notifications (e.g. for screen brightness changes).

I tried this from a similar question:

```
$> sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
mv: cannot stat '/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The notification daemon merely displays the content that applications tell it to display. You must stop notifications at the sending application.

Comment: There are many such applications. Are you seriously telling me there is no global switch?

Comment: You are welcome to patch the NotifyOSD code to contribute such a switch. Or to file bugs against the offending applications that spam irrelevant information to you, so those developers can reduce the notifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable system tray notifications in 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464689/how-to-disable-system-tray-notifications-in-14-04)

Comment: You can disable, or even uninstall it, like [stated here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/464689/how-to-disable-system-tray-notifications-in-14-04), but you may also lose your volume and brightness level popup.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an gnome extension for disabling the notification popups that you might give a whirl.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/

The source code for it is here:

https://github.com/nunofarruca/WindowIsReady_Remover