# How can I log all notify-send actions?

Tags: notification, log, notify-send

I keep getting very strange notifications which go away before I can read them, they are long, and appear at random times, the most recently one came up was during a kernel upgrade, it had a strange icon, and was long, but I didn't manage to read it because it was on the screen so briefly.

So I am wondering if there is any log which logs all calls to `notify-send` which logs the program calling it, and all the parameters given? Or if I can set up such a log to find out what these notifications are about? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: As far as i know notify-send does not support a forced logging. I do have a really ugly workaround in mind which should be the last option/resort: Start a screen-recording and record as long as needed until the message appears. Stop the recording, start playback, jump to related section & pause. Using screenshots might as well be an option if you can trigger them fast enough (i.e. print-screen-key)

Comment: @dufte: Is there not a way with aliases or something which would mean that a script is called instead of it which logs and then passes on the arguments to the real `notify-send`?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history ?

Comment: I would think that a simple python script that listens on DBus for the correct messages, and writes them to a log file, would do very well. Not that I'm offering to write one :-D

Comment: If you are using Gnome, aren't they logged in then notifications menu?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even didn't need a full script...
...but put it in the form of a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file=$1

dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" |\
 grep --line-buffered "string" |\
 grep --line-buffered -e method -e ":" -e '""' -e urgency -e notify -v |\
 grep --line-buffered '.*(?=string)|(?<=string).*' -oPi |\
 grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' |\
 xargs -I '{}' echo {} >> $file
```

#### To run it

- Copy the "script" into an empty file, save it as `keep_log.sh`
- Run it with the logfile as argument with the command

  ```
  /bin/bash /path/to/keep_log.sh /path/to/log.txt
  ```

The answer was retrieved from an [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/697973/72216) (not a dupe), in which this application of the method was mentioned as an example.

The answer I gave there, on its own turn, was based on [this very nice answer,](https://askubuntu.com/a/368875/72216) in which is explained that the method uses `dbus-monitor` to intercept the contents of notify-send. By editing the example there, we can make it write `notify-send` messages to a (log-) file.

### Or, more elegant

...would be to add the date to the logfile, producing a logfile like:

```
---di 10 mei 2016 17:37:20 CEST---
SOme kind of a message!
---di 10 mei 2016 17:37:20 CEST---
The last message was misspelled so here i9s another one
```

In that case, the script would be:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

logfile=$1

dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" |\
grep --line-buffered "string" |\
grep --line-buffered -e method -e ":" -e '""' -e urgency -e notify -v |\
grep --line-buffered '.*(?=string)|(?<=string).*' -oPi |\
grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' |\
xargs -I '{}' \
printf "---$( date )---\n"{}"\n" >> $logfile
```

Comment: Wait, sorry, I'm not sure I fully understand, where is the log stored?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda you can define your own path. I used `/home/jacob/desktop/log.txt` in my test. The file is created if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda ah, sorry, sorry, too much in a hurry... See update.

Comment: Ok, I see now `sender=:1.918 -> destination=:1.16 serial=7 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; ...` etc., but how can I determine who is sending it?

Comment: @vladkras install `d-feet` and run it (a GUI app).  It shows me, e.g., that `org.freedesktop.Notifications` on the Session Bus is associated with `gnome-shell` itself. And the notification I wanted to track down (an obvious one to log and get a timestamp for - ephemeral warnings that `The volume “Filesystem root” has only xxx MB disk space remaining`!) came from 1.49 which is `gsd-housekeeping` on the Session Bus.
So now the question for gnome-shell is how to log notifications, like notify-osd did, I guess?

Comment: I'm getting this sometimes: Error: `xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option`

Comment: @nealmcb see https://askubuntu.com/questions/842935/how-can-i-solve-unmatched-double-quote-error-using-dbus-monitor-in-combination

Comment: Thanks, @JacobVlijm.  Can you make the change to fix this here?  I.e. use `xargs -d '\n' -I '{}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to run one more command after the printf. Tried `printf "---$( date )---\n"{}"\n" >> $logfile && echo hi` and tried the echo in the new line. Neither worked.

Comment: IIUC there's a problem: the `dbus-monitor` process runs only once but it handles multiple messages. As a result 1. the date is the same for all messages and 2. @Andrew your `echo hi` never appears. An idea to solve both problems could be to replace `xargs` with sth like `while read msg; do date +"---%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S---"; echo "$msg"; done`