# How can I solve "unmatched double quote" error using dbus-monitor in combination with xargs?

Tags: command-line, scripts, dbus, xargs

To intercept (`notify-osd`) notifications on Linux (Ubuntu), I am using the `dbus-monitor` script below. Subsequently, the script runs another script (`/opt/nonotifs/nonotifs/silent`) with the intercepted notification as argument, for further processing:

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | \
grep --line-buffered "string" | \
grep --line-buffered -e method -e ":" -e '""' -e urgency -e notify -v | \
grep --line-buffered '.*(?=string)|(?<=string).*' -oPi | \
grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' | \
xargs -I '{}' /opt/nonotifs/nonotifs/silent {}
```

This works flawlessly, ***except*** with notifications by `hplip`.

[image]

When run from a terminal, the script above shows:

```
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
```

When using the option `-0` however, the script delivers no argument at all.

#### What I tried

In some cases, the script subsequently breaks. If that would *always* be the case, It could be worked around by running it in a "keep alive" -wrapper, which I tried. Often however, The script does not terminate, but it stops returning the intercepted notifications nevertheless.

How can I solve this?

### Edit

As suggested by @Serg, I replaced the `xargs...` section by `cat -A`, to see what is passed to `xargs`. This shows that indeed there is an *unmatched double quote* in the notification of `hplip` (the third line), which seems to be a bug in the notification.

The output when running with `cat -A`, calling the notification:

```
"hplip"$ 
"HPLIP Device Status"$ 
"Officejet_Pro_8600$ 
"transient"$
```

Comment: my guess would be that what gets passed to  xargs  has double quote in it. Try verifying that with substituting `cat -A` instead of `xargs` there

Comment: @Serg you are totally right! Be it that it seems a bug in the HP -notification. It outputs `"hplip"$
 "HPLIP Device Status"$
 "Officejet_Pro_8600$
 "transient"$`, which indeed shows an unmatched double quote (in `"Officejet_Pro_8600$`)

Comment: Yup, the guess was right. Might be a bug in their notification, might be not. You have whole lot of pipes with grep, so check those too before making final conclusion.

Comment: @Serg Yeah, clearly a bug in hplip: `"Officejet_Pro_8600$` - an incorrect notification...

Comment: in that case maybe use `tr -d '"'` to delete the double quotes ?

Comment: `tr -d '"'` is used to delete specific characters.  So , you want to place it between last `grep` and `xargs` so , try `grep --line-buffered -v '^\s*$' |  tr -d '"' | xargs . . . . ` Not ideal solution, of course, but at least you don't have to deal with unmatched double quotes then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47615/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-serg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `man xargs`:

```
--delimiter=delim
-d delim
      Input  items  are terminated by the specified character.  Quotes
      and backslash are not special; every character in the  input  is
      taken  literally.   Disables  the  end-of-file  string, which is
      treated like any other argument.  This  can  be  used  when  the
      input consists of simply newline-separated items, although it is
      almost always better to design your program to use --null  where
      this  is  possible.   The  specified  delimiter  may be a single
      character, a C-style character escape such as \n, or an octal or
      hexadecimal escape code.  Octal and hexadecimal escape codes are
      understood as for the printf command.   Multibyte characters are
      not supported.
```

As an example:

```
$ echo '"""' | xargs
\xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
$ echo '"""' | xargs -d '\n'
"""

$ echo '"""' | xargs -d ' ' 
"""
```

Of course, using either may break things, but perhaps not as much as `-0`.

Comment: The second one makes the output always show the before-latest -one. The first one seems to do the job well however with about everything I tried so far, even shows the hplip notification correctly :). Thanks for this!