# Is there any way to watch or access Ubuntu Gnome's native notifications through Python?

Tags: gnome, python, notification

Android does offer that functionality through the 'Notification Access' permission. Is there any way to do the same in Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770218/how-can-i-log-all-notify-send-actions, https://askubuntu.com/questions/697699/execute-a-script-every-time-a-particular-application-makes-a-notification/697973#697973, https://askubuntu.com/a/770896/72216 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/842935/how-can-i-solve-unmatched-double-quote-error-using-dbus-monitor-in-combination on the subject. Not so much python, but you can combine it with python code to do whatever with it. Not sure if it works exactly similar on gnome though, you'll have to test.

Comment: This method sometimes gives outputs which are quite dirty and require cleaning up to put it some use. I just hoped there would be Python library to do this saving me from the hassle. But it seems like I will have to do it myself. Thanks @JacobVlijm !