# Icons are missing in desktop notifications (Facebook and VLC)

Tags: vlc, notification, facebook, icon-themes, budgie

I am using ubuntu budgie remix 17.10 and I have noticed the following thing.

When a notification appears on my screen either from facebook or from vlc
shows the message of the notification the action buttons but instead of the notification icon from vlc or facebook I see a red "X" like the icon is missing

Here is an example:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Manos, removed the answer for now, but could you post the whole output of the dbus-monitor on an incorrect icon? I am not sure the first line is the icon by definition, but the incorrect icon should probably be in the output.

Comment: @JacobVlijm

Chromium
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option
Facebook

This is what I receive from chromium when somebody sends me  a message on facebook

Comment: Aha, then the issue might vary per case, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/842935/how-can-i-solve-unmatched-double-quote-error-using-dbus-monitor-in-combination. Interesting case. I will see if I can get a better read from dbus-monitor.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I do have the same issue...

Comment: For the time being no :( However I noticed that it started happening when my user was removed from the root group