# Is it possible to view the notifications' history on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, notification, notification-area

Is there a way to see/display notifications' history on Ubuntu 18.04?

---

**EDIT:**
I installed **indicator-notifications** following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/105573/822295) but, contrary to what was told in the answer,

> You will find a little mailbox in the panel:
>   [image: icon]

there was no icon of the tool appearing on my top-bar after I rebooted my PC.
Also, I tested the tool using : `notify-send 'test message'`, I got a normal notification as I used to get before installing the tool, but my question is about viewing the history of notifications (like in a log file or something like that), which I didn't get using this tool (may be I miss-used it).

Comment: @karel I edited my post with more details, check it please.

Comment: What version are you using? (via `apt-cache policy indicator-notifications`). I have `indicator-notifications: 0.3.3-0~ppa~bionic` and it isn't working for me either in gnome-shell. I see this recent bug report saying that a fix was uploaded [Bug #1763425 “Not working on bionic” : Bugs : recent-notifications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/recent-notifications/+bug/1763425) , but I can't find the actual code update either at https://code.launchpad.net/~jconti/recent-notifications

Comment: Thank you for asking this question! When `notify-osd` was part of Ubuntu (Unity), it could be run with the "LOG=1" environment variable to log notifications. Now that `gnome-shell` seems to have taken over that notification function itself, I wonder if it has (or should have) a similar way to enable logging.  It seems crazy to me that some of the most important events in Ubuntu show up as notifications, but not in the /var/log files, with helpful timestamps.  E.g. the ephemeral warnings that `The volume “Filesystem root” has only xxx MB disk space remaining!`

Comment: See also this, though it seems kludgy and hard to parse out all the info you really want with shell commands  [How can I log all notify-send actions? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770218/how-can-i-log-all-notify-send-actions)

Comment: @nealmcb I have the same version as you too. And I read about the bug fix but unfortunately, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @nealmcb Unfortunately gnome-shell in 18.04 does not support normal indicators (only app-indicators) so indicator-notifications will not work. (The fix in that bug was just an upload to my ppa of a version compatible with unity and mate on 18.04).

Comment: @JasonConti, please post an answer with what you commented so that others will find it in the future.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  As I recall, you had some Python code a while ago to display and/or log notifications - does that still work? The Python d-bus code I've found seems out-of-date.

Comment: Time flows and nothing happens... any update?

Comment: @PawelDebski Nothing yet unfortunately

Comment: For me it seem a basic design flaw. Hard to imagine that there is nothing in /var/log or that there is nothing in some ini file that can make it happen.

Comment: Curiously it still not answered, I would like to find a solution too

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to view notification history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history)

Comment: @SchoolBusesC2 No, I already explained that it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log all notify-send actions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770218/how-can-i-log-all-notify-send-actions)

Answer (score 3):

The NotifyOSD in Ubuntu does a good job in providing a growl like notification bubble when new event arrive. This is useful if you are always on your computer. If you leave your PC and new notification appears and gone, you won’t be able to know that what you have missed when you return. Recent Notification is a useful applet designed to solve this problem.

Recent Notification works hand in hand with NotifyOSD. It records down all the events notified via NotifyOSD. With a single click, you will be able to view the list of all the past events.

To install in Ubuntu,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications
```

To use it, you have to right click on the panel and select “**Add to Panel**” From the window that pops up, select “**Recent Notification**”.

`notification-add-to-panel`
You should now see a new applet in your Gnome panel.

`notification-applet`
Simply click the applet and it will show a window with all your past notifications.

`notification-window`
Viewing, sorting and managing your notification.
In addition to viewing your recent notification, you can also get it to only show notification from a particular application. For example, I have notification coming from both Pidgin and CloudSN. In the Recent Notification window, I can select from the dropdown list to get it to show only notification from CloudSN.

`notification-select-app`
For each notification, you can also right click to copy the text or to blacklist the application (so that it won’t appear in the list).

`notification-copy-text`
Wrapping up
Recent Notification applet is simple, and useful application designed to do what the NotifyOSD can’t. It might not be suitable for everyone, especially those who hate the idea of cluttering the taskbar with yet another applet. For those who like to keep track of the notified events, this is definitely a nifty app to have. Things that I hope to see is the availability of an indicator-applet (rather than a panel applet), or better still, integrate with the messaging menu.

Comment: I tired this on Pop!_OS 20.10 and could not get it to work. After trying to figure out why, I found that it does not work on GNOME Shell. https://answers.launchpad.net/recent-notifications/+question/676604

Answer (score 1):

Click on the clock, or press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, to see all of the notifications that you have not acted upon.