# Is there a way to see details of past notification in ubuntu 20.04 LTS Gnome desktop

Tags: gnome, 20.04, skype, notification

The issue is I would like to see and dismiss every notification on my own time. But certain notifications hang around in the notification center and some just dissapear (like skype notifications for example).

Is there a way to see all notification history?

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? Providing feedback is useful for the community.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, as of now there is no built-in log of notifications.
Nevertheless, you can easily setup a script that listens to the notifications and logs them, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/770249/226614), e.g.
You would autoexecute the script at startup, [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up), [ref](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-run-script-on-startup-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-server-desktop)
, and voilà!

**Notes**:

1. You might find a lot of (perhaps misleading) links to [`indicator-notifications`](https://github.com/trism/indicator-notifications), *Recent Notification*, *NotifyOSD*. That would not solve your problem.
2. You can test your configuration with [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/notify-send.1.html).

**Related**:

1. [How can I log all notify-send actions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770218/how-can-i-log-all-notify-send-actions)
2. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=291196
3. [Is there a way to view notification history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105566/is-there-a-way-to-view-notification-history)